# Search and replace some text in strings in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to search in a text of multiple lines to see if each line has `sentence="` followed by some text and ended with `" />'`. If yes, see if the text between `sentence="`  and  `" />'` has `"`, if yes, replace it with `'`. For example, one such line is:

```
<number="4" word="start" sentence="I said, "start!"" />
```

I would like to change it to be

```
<number="4" word="start" sentence="I said, 'start!'" />
```

Note that such cases can happen more than once in each single line of the text.

I wonder how to use regex in Python to accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: I assume your example's `sentence` attribute is supposed to be `instance`? (or vice versa)

Comment: @roippi: oops. "instance" should be "sentence"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a callable to `re.sub` to tell it what to replace the match object with:

```
s = """<number="4" word="start" sentence="I said, "start!"" />"""

re.sub(r'(?<=sentence=")(.*)(?=" />)', lambda m: m.group().replace('"',"'"), s)
Out[179]: '<number="4" word="start" sentence="I said, \'start!\'" />'
```

Comment: +1 I coulnt get the last `"` right, with `re.sub(r'sentence="(.*)"\s*/>', lambda x: x.group(0).replace('"', "'"), data)` :(